# Оптимизация кода php

Tags: php

Добрый день! У меня такой вопрос. Как мне можно оптимизировать ниже представленный (надеюсь на нестрогий суд, так как занимаюсь не долго)код.

Делала сайт на Codeigniter, что требовалась. Вывести данные из 2 таблиц(да таблицы не приведены к 3нф т.к. база была сделана до меня и мне не дали время на нормальную проработку базы, а хотят только наращивать функционал). И по требованию было сделано 4 поля обязательных, которые всегда выводятся и 26 необязательны, которые были сделаны чекбоксами(это ужасно) и вот я получаю такой код на выводе.

```
<tr>
                    <th> Станция назначение </th>
                    <th> Станция операции </th>
                    <th> Номер вагона </th>
                    <th> Дата </th>
                    <th> Время </th>

                 <? if($op == "yes"):?>
                <th> ОП </th>
                <? endif;?>
                 <? if($dpr == "yes"):?>
                <th> ДПР </th>
                <? endif;?>
                 <? if($inpoezd == "yes"):?>
                <th> Индекс поезда </th>
                <? endif;?>
                 <? if($gruz == "yes"):?>
```

и т.д.

```
<? foreach ($disla as $item):?>
                    <?

                        $x = $item->naznachenie;
                        $q = $item->operation;
                        for($i=0; $i< count($item->naznachenie); $i++)
                        {
                            if ($x != $y)
                            {
                                echo "<tr><td>".$x."</td><td></td></tr>";
                                $t = true;
                                $y = $x;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $t = false;
                            }
                        }
                    for ($i=0; $i< count($item->operation); $i++)
                    {
                        if ($q != $w or $t == true)
                        {
                            echo "<tr><td></td><td>".$q."</td></tr>";
                            $w = $q;
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>

                    <td><a href="#" style='text-decoration: none;' id="<?=$item->number_vagona?>" onclick="TellId(this)"><?=$item->number_vagona?></a></td>
                    <?

                    $date_out = date("d.m.Y", strtotime($item->date));

                    if(strtotime($date11) == strtotime($date_out) or strtotime($date1) == strtotime($date_out) and ($item->time) > $time)
                    {
                        echo "<td style='color: #3caa3c;'><strong>".$date_out."</strong></td>"; 
                    }
                    elseif(strtotime($date_out) <= strtotime($date5) and strtotime($date_out) > strtotime($date10))
                    {
                        echo "<td style='color: orange;'><strong>".$date_out."</strong></td>"; 
                    }
                     elseif(strtotime($date_out) <= strtotime($date10))
                    {
                        echo "<td style='color: red;'><strong>".$date_out."</strong></td>"; 
                    }

                    else
                        echo "<td><strong>".$date_out."<strong></td>";

                    ?>
                    <td><?=$item->time ?></td>
                    <? if($op == "yes"):?>
                        <td><?=$item->op ?></td>  
                    <? endif;?>

                    <? if($comment == "yes"):?>
                        <td><input onchange="uodate(<?=$item->number_vagona ?>,'comment',this)" type="text"  value="<?=$item->comment ?>" id="noborder"/></td>          
                    <? endif;?>
```

при выводе происходит сравнение первых двух столбцов, вывод даты по цвету.

я его конечно сократила очень сильно, сами представьте 40 столбцов на выбор юзера. 
вроде бы все работает, но скорость работы просто ужасная. Понимаю, что во многом я делала не правильно.
Просьба напишите замечания, где что можно сделать лучше?
Заранее спасибо большое!

Comment: Дам маленький совет! Нужно html встраивать в php а не php в html если не используйется шаблонизатор!

-----------------------

Это же ужасно

    <td><?=$item->time ?></td>
    <? if($op == "yes"):?>
    <td><?=$item->op ?></td>  
    <? endif;?>

не кажется так?

Comment: да, правы, спасибо.

Comment: просто, когда все начиналось не рассчитывалось на такой объем было 6 столбца, которые спокойно выводились.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в Codeigniter не работал, но нас колько знаю это фреймворк в котором реализован паттерн MVC. Если вы не знаетет его - то вперед изучать, иначе вы не сможете эффективно использовать этот да и другие фрэймворки
Т.е. вы хотите сказать что это кусок кода относящийся исключительно к представлению?

Если у вас так много необязательных полей то я бы вам посоветовал посмотреть в сторону использовании  модели EAV (Entity-Attribute-Value) можно почитать  [тут](http://forum.sources.ru/index.php?showtopic=277383)

Comment: ну я его изучала, и все у меня сделано по модели MVC, как только было это возможно(в моем представлении), данный кусок кода представляет вывод таблицы. И я задаю конкретный вопрос, как мне оптимизировать мой вывод учитывая количество столбцов, и что пользователь их может регулировать чекбоксами.

Comment: спасибо, за ссылку буду изучать.